# Query a part of string from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, substring, couchbase

I have the below couchbase query in Java to get an array list of a particular value.

```
Statement statement = select("PlanningId").from(i(CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan.toString()))
                         .where(x("meta().id").like(s("PRODUCTOPTION%")).and(x("Status").eq(s("Ready"))));

    String[] planningIDs = couchbaseRepository.getQueryResult(bucket, statement);
```

This return the output as:

```
[{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}]
```

I need the output with only the values:

```
[{"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}]
```

I am not able to get this using the substring or a split.
How would I achieve this?

Thanks
Emraan

Comment: If you just want to manupulate the resulting String array `planningIds`, you need to create another String array in which you can actually store the required values like `PRODUCTPLANNING_666, PRODUCTPLANNING_777,...`

Comment: Could you please let me know if I need to create a new array list. And if then how do I get only the part of that to be inserted?

Comment: Please clarify me one thing, are you getting this `[{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}]` in a `String` array or an `ArrayList`. Looking at your code snippet, What I'm guessing is you are calling `Arrays.toString(planningIds)`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Its an ArrayList. I am currently calling it as String for value testing.

Comment: In that case what objects does your `ArrayList` hold? Does it hold Objects of type `PlanningId` or just `String` objects?

Comment: it would have just string with data like:    [{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}]. From this I need to create a new list of only the values like {"PRODUCTPLANNING_666", "PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}.

Comment: Asking one last question, since your question doesn't clarify many things. So are `{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}` and `{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}` two seperate strings in your `ArrayList` or a single String? In other words, does your List hold these two as seperate objects?

Comment: No problem. Its a single object, as I am able to get it printed as below: `String[] strPlanning = this.getPlanningDataID();
System.out.println(strPlanning[0].toString());`. And the Output is `[{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, on each query if the returned result contains a single `String` like: `{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"},....`, the process to extract only the required part of `{"PRODUCTPLANNING_XXX"},...` can be done as follows:

Say you have a String like

`String planningIds = {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"},....{"PlanningId":"PRODUCTPLANNING_NNN"}`

and if you want to capture each `{"PRODUCTPLANNING_XXX}` in a single `String`,

```
StringBuilder finalResult = new StringBuilder();
        String[] results = allPlanningIds.split(",");
        for(String eachPlanningId : results){
            String[] resultPlanningIds = eachPlanningId.split(":");
            if(resultPlanningIds.length != 2){
                continue;
            }
            String result = "{" + resultPlanningIds[1];
            finalResult = finalResult.append(result + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(finalResult);
```

or if you want to capture each `{"PRODUCTPLANNING_XXX}` as seperate `String` objects within an `ArrayList`, in the above code snippet, change `StringBuilder finalResult = new StringBuilder();` to `List<String> finalResults = new ArrayList<>();` and

`finalResult = finalResult.append(result + ",");` 
to `finalResults.add(result)`.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

**Note:** Please check the end / null conditions of the `String[] results` array.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the Separate String objects and I get the out put as    `[{"PRODUCTPLANNING_666"}, {"PRODUCTPLANNING_777"}]]`. I get an additional   `]`. Not sure why?

Comment: That's because, the original `String` contains `]` at the end and that will be the part of last item in the `String[] results` array. If you want to skip that you can do a `subString()` operation on the final result.